# Detection phantomjs by vk.com

Tags: phantomjs

Is it possible to grab some data from vk.com through phantomjs? Whatever i do, it redirects me to https://vk.com/badbrowser.php, it seems like vk determines that i am not a real browser. Can anyone help me? I just want vk to return me the same content like i see through my real browser.

I tried to enable javascript and cookies, but it did not work

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open("https://vk.com", function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: maybe try headless chrome

Comment: as i remember, i could not get pages of vk.com with curl, but now, i tested it again and see it redirects to m.vk.com and works, content is served.